# Focus a certain input on a list of dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of dynamically generated inputs.

```
input --> onClick new Input beneath
[dynamically added]input
input
```

How can give just this dynamically added input focus?

The input has the textInput ref. This partly works:

```
componentWillUpdate(){
this.textInput.focus();
}
```

Yet, just works or the first new Input. Then it seems like the logic breaks.

the inputs are .map() from an array. Is there a way to either say, if the current rendered element has el.isActive to focus it. Or just say focus the input with the index 5?

**CODE**

Inputsgenerating file/component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash'

class SeveralInputs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ' '
        }
        this.showIndex = this
            .showIndex
            .bind(this)
        this.map = this
            .map
            .bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this
            .handleChange
            .bind(this);
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        this.textinput && this
            .textInput
            .focus();

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <ul>
                {this.map()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
    map() {
        {
            return this
                .props
                .data
                .map((name, index) => <li
                    onKeyPress={this
                    .showIndex
                    .bind(this, index)}
                    key={index}><input
                    onChange={this
                    .handleChange
                    .bind(this, index)}
                    task={this.task}
                    value={name.value}
                    ref={(input) => {
                    this.textInput = input;
                }}
                    type="text"/>{name.value}</li>)
        }
    }
    handleChange(index, e) {
        let data = this
            .props
            .data
            .splice(index, 1, {
                value: e.target.value,
                isActive: true
            })
        this
            .props
            .refreshState(data);
    }
    showIndex(index, e) {
        if (e.which === 13 || e.keyPress === 13) {
            let data = this.props.data[index].isActive = false
            data = this
                .props
                .data
                .splice(index + 1, 0, {
                    value: ' ',
                    isActive: true
                })
            this
                .props
                .refreshState(data);
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}

export default SeveralInputs
```

The data that lives in the parent component

```
const data = [
  {
    value: 0,
    isActive: true
  }, {
    value: 2,
    isActive: false
  }
]
```

The parents state:

this.state = {
  error: null,
  data
};

The parents render

```
render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {/* <Input/> */}
        {/* <SeveralItems refreshState={this.refreshState} data={this.state.data.value}/>  */}

        <SeveralInputs refreshState={this.refreshState} data={this.state.data}/> {/* <SeveralInputsNested refreshState={this.refreshState} data={this.state.data}/> {this.items()} */}
      </div>
    );
  }
  refreshState(data) {
    this.setState({data: this.state.data})
    console.log(this.state.data)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is that in `refreshState` you pass some `data` that you do not handle, try this:

```
refreshState(newData) {
    this.setState({data: newData})
}
```

And trying to log `this.state` right after won't work [because](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) :

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.

Comment: If I just change the function to what you wrote the state becomes empty. The callback/componentDidMount was meant for the logging, right. As for the issue, the state update seems to be working. It might not be the typical approach, but I'm not sure it interferes with my focusing the inputs.